# How can I configure Xdebug for only one of the two applications running on my server?

Tags: php, xdebug

I have a Vagrant virtual machine with two PHP applications installed. I always debug application A, but Xdebug is globally configured and watches both applications.

How can I configure Xdebug only for application A?

Comment: General idea: configure your environment (Apache/nginx/etc) to use different php.ini for different sites .. and disable xdebug in such "unwanted" site configs.

Answer (score 0):

There is the function:

> void xdebug_disable() 
>   Disables stack traces Disable showing stack
>   traces on error conditions.

So if you want just to get rid of the displayed Stack Traces, you can use this (it doesn't disable xDebug entirely).